# How to modify the _start_method in python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a custom embedded python interpreter ([the gem5 simulator](https://www.gem5.org/)), and I would like to use this to spawn new processes with the multiprocessing module.

It works fine for simple use cases. I can use either `fork` or `spawn` start methods and successfully execute functions in parallel.

However, I would like to pass arguments to the executable *before* the main multiprocessing command. E.g., instead of

`<python executable> -c 'from multiprocessing.spawn import spawn_main; spawn_main(tracker_fd=5, pipe_handle=9)' --multiprocessing-fork`

I would like be able to do something like

`<python executable> **<my options here>** -c 'from multiprocessing.spawn import spawn_main; spawn_main(tracker_fd=5, pipe_handle=9)' --multiprocessing-fork`

As far as I can tell this isn't possible with the current multiprocessing module. However, I would rather not reimplement the wheel if there's a way I can leverage multiprocessing.

Comment: I have no idea what `multiprocessing.spawn` is. Is this something particular to your custom Python interpreter or have you created your own `multiprocessing` module? Likewise, I don't recognize the `--multiprocessing-fork` interpreter option. Is it just the start method being used that you would like to control from the command line?

Comment: There are three different start methods supported. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods) for details. I would like to customize the context/start method. When using the `spawn` method, the command line parameter `--multiprocessing-fork` is used. See the code [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/254aaa7981d8773658fb14795da5dec888c95f93/Lib/multiprocessing/spawn.py#L93). Reimplementing the `multiprocessing` module seems like the only path forward, but I was hoping there would be another option.

Comment: No. You can call `multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')` if you want to set the method of creating new processes to *spawn*. There is no such attribute as  `multiprocessing.spawn`.

Comment: There definitely is a `multiprocessing.spawn` module. I linked to the code in cpython above. I understand how to set a different start method. What I need is a way to *customize the method that python creates a new process.* Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You are right and I stand corrected.

Comment: I cannot find any documentation on `multiprocessing.spawn`. It is beginning to look like it is a "private" module used by `multiprocessing`. If so, you should not be using it. Anyway, can't you pass something like  `-c 'from multiprocessing import set_start_method; set_start_method("spawn"); etc.'` to the Python interpreter?

Comment: Yes, it's an internal module. I can pass other commands via `-c`. However, what I would like to do is call something like `set_start_method("gem5_spawn")` or somehow control what command is executed internally when `multiprocessing` creates a new process. At this point I've resigned to extending the classes in `multiprocessing` and copying and pasting when extending doesn't work.